# Rescript open is not bringing functions into scope

Tags: module, rescript

How is `open` and *module prefixing* supposed to work in rescript and rescript-react.  It doesn't appear to be adhering to the documentation. For example, I have a file reader module

**FileReader.res**

```
module FileReader = {
  type fileReader
  type file = {"name": string, "lastModified": int, "size": int, "type__": string}

  @new external createFileReader: unit => fileReader = "FileReader"

  @bs.send
  external readAsDataURL: (fileReader, file) => unit = "readAsDataURL"

  let onload: (fileReader, string => unit) => unit = %raw(`
    function (reader, cb) {
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        cb(e.target.result);
      }
    }
  `)

  let fileToDataUrl: (file, string => unit) => unit = (file, continue) => {
    let reader = createFileReader()
    onload(reader, continue)
    readAsDataURL(reader, file)
  }
}
```

That I am trying to use from a react component:

**Upload.res**

```
open FileReader
let k = x => (_ => x)
let setState = stateHook => (newVal => stateHook(_ => newVal))
let firstFileFromEvent = event => ReactEvent.Form.target(event)["files"][0]

@react.component
let make = () => {
    let (dataUrl, setDataUrl) = React.useState(k(""))
    let setDataUrlState = setState(setDataUrl)

    let fileOnChange = (event) =>
        event ->
            firstFileFromEvent ->
            FileReader.fileToDataUrl(setDataUrlState)

    <div>
        <input type_="file" onChange=fileOnChange/>
        <img src=dataUrl/>
    </div>
}
```

The only way to get the code to compile is to

1. open
2. reference with the module name

my understanding is that you only need to do one or the other.  If I remove the `open` statement, this is the output of the compiler

> We've found a bug for you!
> src/Upload.res:15:13-36
>
> 13 ┆     event ->   14 ┆         firstFileFromEvent ->   15 ┆
> FileReader.fileToDataUrl(setDataUrlState)   16 ┆    17 ┆
>
> The value fileToDataUrl can't be found in FileReader

Adding the open statement back and changing the statement `FileReader.fileToDataUrl(setDataUrlState)` to `fileToDataUrl(setDataUrlState)` results in this exception:

> We've found a bug for you!
> src/Upload.res:15:13-25
>
> 13 ┆     event ->   14 ┆         firstFileFromEvent ->   15 ┆
> fileToDataUrl(setDataUrlState)   16 ┆    17 ┆
>
> The value fileToDataUrl can't be found

The source i posted with both the `open` statement and the module prefix to the function call, compiles but has a warning:

> Warning number 44
> src/Upload.res:1:1-15
>
> 1 │ open FileReader   2 │    3 │ let k = x => (_ => x)
>
> this open statement shadows the module identifier FileReader (which
> is later used)

I am on a mac; using rescript 9.1.4;

Answer (score 3):

In rescript, every code file is itself a module. By putting your code into `FileReader.res` you've already created a module called `FileReader`. And by using `module FileReader = { ... }` you're creating *another* submodule called `FileReader` inside it.

The simple solution would then be to just not wrap it in a submodule. Alternatively, you could also `open FileReader.FileReader`.

What the warning is telling you is that when you `open FileReader`, you're importing another module called `FileReader` which shadows (i.e. hides) the top-level module that's also called `FileReader`.